# C# SignatureDescription for SHA256

Tags: c#, sign, sha256

I am working on a c# signing application. At one point, a System.Security.Cryptography.SignatureDescription needs to be obtained. Does anyone know why description1 below contains a valid structure, while description2 is null? Changing from .Net3.5 to .Net4.5.1 did not help.

```
SignatureDescription description1 = CryptoConfig.CreateFromName("http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1") as SignatureDescription;

SignatureDescription description2 = CryptoConfig.CreateFromName("http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256") as SignatureDescription;
```

It didn't work for SHA512 either. URIs obtained from [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlsec-algorithms/#RSA).

Comment: Create from name doesn't mean you need to enter a URL. Why should changing to .NET 4.5.1 yield another result (if that was true, .NET was very badly backwards compatible).

Comment: re .Net, I figured, however sometimes it doesn't harm to try. Regarding CreateFromName(), I tried using the URI because that works for SHA1. If there are any similar methods to create a SignatureDescription given a particular hashing algorithm, that would be fine.

Comment: Btw, one could pass "SHA1" or "SHA256" to CreateFromName(), however the SignatureDescription is not available then for either algorithms. So it seems the full URI is required to get the SignatureDescription.

Comment: I am now specifying the signature description strings myself. Once again, this is working for SHA1 but not for SHA256. Any thoughts?


SignatureDescription desc = new SignatureDescription();
desc.DeformatterAlgorithm = "System.Security.Cryptography.RSAPKCS1SignatureDeformatter";
desc.DigestAlgorithm = "System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256CryptoServiceProvider";
desc.FormatterAlgorithm = "System.Security.Cryptography.RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter";
desc.KeyAlgorithm = "System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider";

HashAlgorithm hash = desc.CreateDigest();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently RSA-SHA256 is not supported in .Net 3.5. However there's a workaround which can be found here:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6438011b-92fb-4123-a22f-ad071efddf85/xml-digital-signature-with-sha256-algorithm

Comment: The workaround it says there is kinda odd. It calls `CryptoConfig.AddAlgorithm` which is not implemented in 3.5 but in 4.0... If you stick to 3.5 and follow that workaround you should consider [Codeplex CryptoConfig2](http://www.codeplex.com/clrsecurity/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Security.Cryptography.CryptoConfig2) otherwise it is unlikely you would get it working.